# Why doesn't "sed" pick up on command?

Tags: bash, sed

`When using sed and trying to pull out a specific line, it looses the p portion of "sed -n (x)p test.txt"

I'm trying to look at a line and see if its A or B.

```
sed -n 3p test.txt
```

works fine, but i'm trying to do:

```
sed -n $(Count) test.txt
```

This doesn't work

```
sed -n $($Count)p test.txt
```

Doesn't work

```
Count=$(cat -n test.txt | grep -o [0-9]* | tail -1)

until [ $Count = 0 ]; do
    if [[ $(sed -n $(Count)p test.txt) = Him ]] || [[ $(sed -n $(Count)p model.txt) = He ]]
        then
        echo "This is a Boy Word"
    elif [[ $(sed -n $(Count)p model.txt) = Her ]] || [[ $(sed -n $(Count)p model.txt) = She ]]
        then
        echo "This is an Girl Word"
    fi
    let Count=Count-1
    sleep 1
done
```

I'm expecting :
This is a Boy Word

This is a Boy Word

This is a Girl Word

This is a Girl Word...
Until it has gone through all the lines,

```
However I'm getting (with sed -n $($Count)p test.txt)
Line 17: 3: command not found
Line 20: 3: command not found
Line 17: 2: command not found
Line 17: 2: command not found


Or (with sed -n $(Count)p test.txt
Line 17: Count: command not found
Line 20: Count: Command not found
Line 17: Count: Command not Found
Line 20: Count: command not found
```

Comment: Why are you using `$(Count)` in some places and the (correct) `$Count` in others?

Comment: If your referring to the middle portion, $Countp is what would be typed, so im trying to seperate $Count and p

Comment: The syntax `$(Count)` means to run the `Count` command and substitute its output into the command.

Comment: The syntax to use a variable is `$Count` or `${Count}`, not `$(Count)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the full form `${Count}` to separate the variable name from an adjacent character.

```
sed -n ${Count}p test.txt
```

Or, simply quote the parameter expansion:

```
sed -n "$Count"p test.txt
```